# Problem with Wordpress HTML and Shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

My website have a bug. Sometime ( frequently) the one section become super long, I use Chrome Dev Tool and see this:

[image]

I tried UX builder ( I use Flatsome ) but there is nothing I can do. I tried to go to page edit to see HTML code but I only saw Shortcode. How to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Flatsome uses UX Builder. Make sure you have it enabled and click "Edit with UX Builder" to use the interface to edit your content.

Comment: I tried but everything in UX builder is ok. I believe this bug happen because I use WP Rocket Minify HTML. I found that cause all blank space become stick togetger so I disable it. And this problem happened.